# Direct2D erasing the background with WM_ERASEBKGND?

Tags: c++, winapi, directx

It seems like I've learn it hard way, if we use Direct2D for painting then one must not use `WM_ERASEBKGND` to handle background erasing, but I may be wrong on this so here is the problem:

I register my drawing window with null brush to let me manually handle background erasure:

```
WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

wcex.hbrBackground = nullptr;
// etc...
```

This will let system generate `WM_ERASEBKGND` and here is the implementation for background erasure which btw. works just fine:

```
// case WM_ERASEBKGND:
BOOL DrawableWindow::OnEraseBackground(WPARAM wParam)
{
    HRESULT hr = CreateGraphicsResources();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        RECT rc{ };
        GetClientRect(mhWnd, &rc);
        const HDC hDC = reinterpret_cast<HDC>(wParam);

        // ID2D1DCRenderTarget
        hr = mpContextRender->BindDC(hDC, &rc);

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            DiscardGraphicsResources();
            return FALSE;
        }

        mpContextRender->BeginDraw();
        mpContextRender->Clear(mBackground); // D2D1::ColorF background color (ie. green)
        hr = mpContextRender->EndDraw();

        if (FAILED(hr) || hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
        {
            DiscardGraphicsResources();
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    // NOTE: Return value sets the PAINTSTRUCT.fErase
    // which the OnPaint() handler can use to determine if painting the backgound is needed
    return FALSE;
}
```

OK, background has been set up, now let's paint over that background!
See comment in code where background is conditionally erased.

```
// case WM_PAINT:
void DrawableWindow::OnPaint()
{
    HRESULT hr = CreateGraphicsResources();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps{ };

        BeginPaint(mhWnd, &ps);

        // ID2D1HwndRenderTarget
        mpWindowRender->BeginDraw();

        // ***THE PROBLEM IS HERE***
        // This value is nonzero if WM_ERASEBKGND erased the background!
        if (ps.fErase)
        {
            // We clear client area only if WM_ERASEBKGND returned FALSE!
            mpWindowRender->Clear(mBackground); // D2D1::ColorF background color (ie. green)
        }

        // We do drawing routuine here...
        // ...
        // done painting

        hr = mpWindowRender->EndDraw();

        if (FAILED(hr) || hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
        {
            DiscardGraphicsResources();
        }

        EndPaint(mhWnd, &ps);
    }
}
```

Ok, this does not work, because once `BeginDraw()` is called the background will turn black and our background which was erased during `WM_ERASEBKGND` is gone!

The check `if (ps.fErase)` inside `OnPaint()` handler will not be executed because it is `FALSE`, it is false because background has been erased inside the `WM_ERASEBKGND`

The result is that background is completely black, and when I resize the window I can see in miliseconds my original background which soon turns into black and ofc. the screen flickers due to color difference.

So the question is, how do I retain background which was set up in `WM_ERASEBKGND`?
Is returning `FALSE` from `WM_ERASEBKGND` really the only solution here?

What's the point of `WM_ERASEBKGND` message then? and why does the `BeginDraw()` ignore my background from `WM_ERASEBKGND` and turn the background black?

Other drawings are visible ofc. it's just that background is lost.

Comment: You can surely make your life a lot easier by simply dropping the native windowing client area. That's what the [WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) extended window style is for. With that out of the way, you have full control over the window contents. [High-Performance Window Layering Using the Windows Composition Engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/june/windows-with-c-high-performance-window-layering-using-the-windows-composition-engine) explains how to go about that.

Comment: @IInspectable ok thanks, I'll check that out, although I'm interested why is background erased twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic window rendering with GDI is revolving around incremental updates to the single image buffer. Typically redrawing a (partially transparent) window would require securing write access to the image buffer, clipping update region, requesting parent window to draw its background, making this window draw its background and then finally making this window draw some updated content.

With DirectX things are different. Typically rendering is at least dual buffered. And the content of those buffers is swapped rather than copied. That is content of the previous frame (that is currently presented) is not available when rendering and then gets discarded after buffers are swapped. So rendering is performed from scratch every time while handling of `WM_ERASEBKGND` is simplified to doing nothing and just returning `TRUE` to indicate that background has been erased so we won't get this message repeated.

Comment: Thank you for concrete answer, I had some feeling it must be that way but didn't know why, and your confirmation is an end to this problem.